# WPF TreeView parent node binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

I have the following classes -

```
public class A : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Child> Children { get; set; }

    ...
}

public class Child : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string InstanceName { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

And here is my TreeView XAML -

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfClassA}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=InstanceName}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

In this case, the parent class A name is not displayed. How can I show the `Name` property on class `A` as well as the `InstanceName` property on the `Child` class.

Comment: your properties need to be public

Comment: They are public in real life i'll make the edit so it's more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=InstanceName}"/>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Is actually the template for your A class. It should be:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}">
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <!-- this is how Child is visualised-->
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=InstanceName}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
    <!-- this is how A is visualised-->
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

For better code visibility you can write them in resource section as two separate templates:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="Child_template">
     <!-- this is how Child is visualised-->
     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=InstanceName}"/>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>

<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="A_template" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Child_template}">
    <!-- this is how A is visualised-->
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Hope this helps.
For reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd759035(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: Hi Didier - thanks for your answer. I'm getting an error: ' Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource.' when using this code. Is there some additional change I need to make ?

Comment: This means that you have added some items manually. Probably you use some csharp to ad items somewhere. You can not ad children by code and by ItemsSource property at the same time.